# Network apache server for windows clients using CentOs 5.5

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, centos5

I just installed a new server for replacing a Windows XP in a small office, the clients are windows pcs and the new CentOs 5.5 is running a LAMPP setup.

The clients are unable to connect to the server for using a WebApp (http://newserver)

The WebApp is working perfectly locally, so what did I miss? iptables? firewall?

Thanks.

Comment: Can users access the server via IP address? i.e http://10.1.1.111:80

Comment: @Brian, yes, they can..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing - a DNS entry? You don't say you did that.
/edit - no longer a guess. If you didn't edit DNS (or every HOSTS file), then of course the clients can't resolve the Domain Name to the IP address.

Comment: Is really necesary to specify a DNS entry in a isolated network? In the previous windows server wasn't.

Comment: Yes. Something is required to translate names to IP addresses. You were using something to identify the old server previously. Either DNS and you didn't know it, or possibly NetBIOS or WINS.

Comment: mfinni, how can I do that?

Comment: What server(s) are your client machines using for DNS now? Add the entry there.

Comment: @mfinni, thanks, I found a quick the solution here: http://serverfault.com/questions/214811/centos-box-access-by-name

Comment: Using Samba and WINS? As long as you're not going to grow much, that's perfectly fine for a small workgroup. DNS is the standard and is used by and supported on every platform you're likely to find. WINS will be more fiddly, especially if you add any non-Windows machines as clients. If you do much IT work, learn about DNS - it will pay off in no time.

Comment: And I will do that, I just get in the linux server thing and I'm very interested..

Answer (score 2):

A few things to get you started:

- What type of error you do mean when you say "unable to connect"? The type of error you get here may help narrow in on the source of the issue. If it is a DNS error then your "newserver" host name is not being resolved. If it is a connection timeout type of error then it may be a server connectivity or Ethernet setup issue. An immediate "connection denied" type may be a misconfigured firewall. Any sort of Apache error page is likely a server misconfiguration.
- Double-check the server's Ethernet configuration (ifconfig).
- Try to ping/telnet/ssh/ftp into the server from a client machine (depending what services you have available on the server and network). If this doesn't work troubleshoot this issue in more detail until you find the cause and fix it.

Comment: The server name "newserver" cannot be resolved. I try with the IP address and is working just fine. I already changed the configuration in the file '/etc/sysconfig/network' and in the file '/etc/hosts'. Well, I renamed the local.localdomain to 'newserver'. Is that correct?

Comment: Assuming you mean '/etc/hosts' on the server then this only will let the server access itself with the "newserver" name. Ideally you want whatever intranet DNS to correctly resolve the "newserver" host name. Temporarily you can also use the hosts file on the Windows clients (\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts).

Comment: The alternative solution will work just great, the name 'oldserver' is correctly resolved by the network DNS and points to the old server wich is still operating. This let me believe that there's is something else to do with the new server.

Answer (score 1):

Check to ensure that you have allowed traffic on port 80 in your firewall config (/etc/sysconfig/iptables).

Also check your logs for httpd, message, security.

Comment: Mike, thanks, the server is allowing any client to connect by using the ip address. The issue seems to be related to the server's name: It cannot be resolved.